How does Independent Component Analysis fit into a machine learning problem?
Suppose we have a regression problem, such as estimating the average duration customers had to wait in line at an ice cream shop, and our available features are the number of ice cream bars sold, the number of cones dispensed, and the volume of soft serve dispensed over that time interval.  The idea of the example is that number of ice cream bars may be informative with or without the other feature(s), but only one of number of cones and volume of soft serve is expected to be informative, since very few customers ask for a cone without soft serve or vice versa.
Principle Component Analysis could be used as a preprocessing step wrapped around the regression algorithm.  We might expect PCA to return $1$ reasonable principle component predominantly influenced by the ice cream bar feature, $1$ reasonable principle component predominantly influenced by the cones and soft serve features jointly, and $1$ really lousy principle component predominantly influenced by the cones and soft serve features jointly which we could then drop from the problem.  Of course, we might also learn that the ice cream bar feature is more correlated to the other features than was obvious at the outset.
How would we have to modify this example to do Independent Component Analysis instead?  My first way of thinking was to modify the regression problem to predict multiple quantities; maybe we keep the same $3$ features but want to estimate the average duration customers had to wait in line, the number of customers who used the restroom, and the volume of garbage produced in the building.  However, I think this is conflating the entire regression problem with the preprocessing step.  So let's assume we're sticking with just average wait duration.
Discarding the above paragraph, my current understanding is that what ICA would do is partition the training data points into multiple strata, $3$ in this example because we fed it $3$ features, and return a set of principle components (maybe now referred to as independent components but effectively identical) for each stratum.  Since prior to our decision to drop unimportant components the number PCA returns is also the number of features, this has the corollary that the total number of components returned by ICA is always the square of the number of features.  It would then be up to us to decide whether to drop components from each stratum, and then plug each of the remaining strata into a regression algorithm separately.  So effectively, we would have branched $1$ machine learning problem into $3$, and it may or may not destroy the point of ICA to aggregate over the conclusions we draw from each problem.
Is this an appropriate problem and explanation for ICA?  If not, then is there some other problem that could be modified to illustrate the contrast between PCA and ICA without using an entirely separate (even if more standard) example for each? (Bonus points if an answer also includes a clear description of the PCA dual problem and ICA dual problem in terms of the above ice cream example.)

Isn't ICA a technique for separating one time series into several, the so-called "cocktail party problem" where human ears/brains can separate the time series of how the eardrum is vibrated into distinct conversations so you can focus on your date and tune out the rest of the party? (Maybe you separate a song into guitar, drums, vocals, etc.) That doesn't sound like the setup for your problem where you have multiple time series already separated from each other.

@Dave Hmmm, that sounds about right, although I got the impression from this geometry (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_e4SN4TWlgY&t=1077s) that ICA is something like a generalization of PCA, but I can't quite think of a regression problem (even without the time series facet) which could utilize either PCA or ICA and draws out the contrast between the two.

The typical use of ICA is to solve something like the cocktail party problem, where you want to decompose the sound in a crowded room into the background noise and what someone is saying to you in a conversation. Another use of this could be to tease out the guitar/vocals/percussion/tuba of a song, given the entirety of the audio. Whatever specific problem you aim to solve, the idea is that you have a combination of time series that you want to decompose into multiple time series.
That does not sound like your problem.
A use I could see for ICA, however, is in engineering multiple features derived from the same time series. You might observe a time series that is a combination of multiple time series, same as how your eardrum vibrates to generate a time series but that vibration is caused by fifty conversations in the party room, only one of which is the conversation with your date on which you want to focus. If you give the model each individual time series that you generate using ICA, it might be better able to weight each one and downweight the noise.

So is ICA inherently reliant on the broader ML problem being a time series, whereas PCA is not?  Otherwise, is it possible to modify your audio example to use PCA to illustrate the difference, or are PCA and ICA just not used in similar contexts at all?

That goes beyond my knowledge of ICA. $//$ PCA isn't so explicit about decomposing data into constituents. ICA might be used to separate a noisy room into background and your date's voice, a song into guitar/drums/vocals/trumpet, etc, but the idea is to break one signal into many. PCA finds uncorrelated vectors that account for the total variance, transforming data of dimension $k$ into other data of dimension $k$. @user10478
